# Intercepting JSON request and using a custom deserializer

Tags: json, web-services, rest, jersey-2.0, json-deserialization

I have written a custom deserializer for my request dto; When I post my JSON request, the request is not getting trapped in the deserializer.
Is their something specific we need to do so that the request falls in the deserializer ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the JSON serializer/deserializer to use the custom deserializer for conversion. @JsonSerialize should be used on top of the class for this.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)    
public class MyClass{
}
```